# Is the gdiff library obsolete?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I just had a closer look at the [gdiff library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gdiff) and wondered if some of the work there could be shifted into GHC Generics and/or Typeables.

To make this a solid question: could the library be improved and deflated by utilizing features available in current ghc versions?

Comment: The functionality of `gdiff` is hardly obsolete. But the question seems to be if the library could be expressed using other approaches to generic programming. The answer to the latter question is a qualified yes. There is for example `gdiff-ig` which reimplements it on top of "instant generics". There are complicated tradeoffs, though, and I'm not sure if such a discussion is in scope for SO.