# Using Text.Generic.Diff to generate output containing "inserted" / "deleted" markers

Tags: haskell, tree, diff

I am using the Haskell [gdiff](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gdiff) package to calculate differences between trees.  The output of the diff algorithm is an "edit script", which describes a sequence of operations that transforms the "before" tree to the "after" tree.  gdiff provides a "patch" function which applies the edit script to the "before" tree, therefore generating the "after" tree.

What I need to do is modify this patch operation so that the output is an "after" tree in which the modifications are highlighted.

As an example, imagine that the tree is a document AST.  I want to generate an output which shows insertions / deletions, inline in the "after" document.

So far, I have written a program which successfully uses gdiff to compute differences between instances of a simple binary tree data structure.  What I can't figure out is how to modify the resulting edit script so that it injects "inserted" and "deleted" markers when the patch operation is executed.

Can anyone help?

## Diffing two binary trees

Here is my binary tree data structure:

```
data Tree = Node String Tree Tree
          | Empty
          deriving Show
```

And here are my example "before" and "after" trees:

```
before :: Tree
before =
  Node "root"
    (Node "A"
      (Empty)
      (Empty)
    )
    (Empty)

after :: Tree
after =
  Node "root"
    (Node "A"
      (Node "B" Empty Empty)
      (Empty)
    )
    (Empty)
```

The diff is executed as follows:

```
runDiff :: EditScript TreeFamily Tree Tree
runDiff = diff before after

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn ("before     = " ++ (show before))
  putStrLn ("after      = " ++ (show after))

  let edit = runDiff
  putStrLn ("edit       = " ++ (show edit))

  let compressed = compress edit
  putStrLn ("compressed = " ++ (show compressed))

  let result = patch edit before
  putStrLn ("result     = " ++ (show result))
```

(I'll come back to the definition of `TreeFamily` in a moment.)

The output is:

```
before     = Node "root" (Node "A" Empty Empty) Empty
after      = Node "root" (Node "A" (Node "B" Empty Empty) Empty) Empty
edit       = Cpy Node $ Cpy "root" $ Cpy Node $ Cpy "A" $ Ins Node $ Ins "B" $ Cpy Empty $ Cpy Empty $ Cpy Empty $ Ins Empty $ End
compressed = Cpy Node $ CpyTree $ Cpy Node $ CpyTree $ Ins Node $ Ins "B" $ CpyTree $ CpyTree $ CpyTree $ Ins Empty $ End
result     = Node "root" (Node "A" (Node "B" Empty Empty) Empty) Empty
```

## Proposed strategy: process the edit script

I think that I can implement the "generate marked-up after tree" operation by processing the edit script so that `... $ Ins Node $ ...` is replaced with `... $ Ins InsNode $ ...`, where `InsNode` is another `Tree` constructor:

```
data Tree = Node String Tree Tree
          | InsNode String Tree Tree
          | Empty
          deriving Show
```

(And similarly for deletions, but this post focuses only on insertion.)

The processed edit script would then be fed to the existing gdiff patch function.

## TreeFamily definition

The gdiff library requires the user to define a "family datatype".  Here is my definition.  Note that I have included the `InsNode` type.  Although this doesn't appear in the input data, I *think* gdiff will need to know about it in order to perform the `Node` to `InsNode` substitution described above.

```
data TreeFamily :: * -> * -> * where
    Node'       ::           TreeFamily Tree (Cons String (Cons Tree (Cons Tree Nil)))
    InsNode'    ::           TreeFamily Tree (Cons String (Cons Tree (Cons Tree Nil)))
    String'     :: String -> TreeFamily String Nil
    Empty'      ::           TreeFamily Tree Nil


instance Family TreeFamily where
    decEq Node' Node'                  = Just(Refl, Refl)
    decEq InsNode' InsNode'            = Just(Refl, Refl)
    decEq (String' s1) (String' s2)
                | s1 == s2             = Just (Refl, Refl)
                | otherwise            = Nothing
    decEq Empty' Empty'                = Just(Refl, Refl)
    decEq _ _                          = Nothing

    fields Node' (Node s t1 t2)        = Just (CCons s (CCons t1 (CCons t2 CNil)))
    fields InsNode' (InsNode s t1 t2)  = Just (CCons s (CCons t1 (CCons t2 CNil)))
    fields (String' _) _               = Just CNil
    fields Empty' Empty                = Just CNil
    fields _ _                         = Nothing

    apply Node' (CCons s (CCons t1 (CCons t2 CNil)))    = Node s t1 t2
    apply InsNode' (CCons s (CCons t1 (CCons t2 CNil))) = InsNode s t1 t2
    apply (String' s) CNil                              = s
    apply Empty' CNil                                   = Empty

    string Node'       = "Node"
    string InsNode'    = "InsNode"
    string (String' s) = show s
    string Empty'      = "Empty"


instance Type TreeFamily Tree where
    constructors = [ Concr Node', Concr InsNode', Concr Empty' ]

instance Type TreeFamily String where
    constructors = [ Abstr String' ]
```

## First attempt at a processEdit function

The function which processes an `EditScript` to perform the `Node` to `InsNode` substitution should have the same signature as the `compress` function, namely:

```
processEdit :: (Family f) => EditScriptL f txs tys -> EditScriptL f txs tys
```

I can write the following identity equations ...

```
processEdit End         = End
processEdit (Ins  c  d) = Ins  c   (processEdit d)
processEdit (Del  c  d) = Del  c   (processEdit d)
processEdit (CpyTree d) = CpyTree  (processEdit d)
processEdit (Cpy  c  d) = Cpy  c   (processEdit d)
```

... but I don't know how to modify the `Ins` equation to perform the substitution.  Can anyone help?

## Complete test program for reference

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances     #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs                 #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures        #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoImplicitPrelude     #-}


module Main where

import Prelude
import Data.Generic.Diff


-- Data types --

data Tree = Node String Tree Tree
          | InsNode String Tree Tree
          | Empty
          deriving Show


-- GADT Family --

data TreeFamily :: * -> * -> * where
    Node'       ::           TreeFamily Tree (Cons String (Cons Tree (Cons Tree Nil)))
    InsNode'    ::           TreeFamily Tree (Cons String (Cons Tree (Cons Tree Nil)))
    String'     :: String -> TreeFamily String Nil
    Empty'      ::           TreeFamily Tree Nil


instance Family TreeFamily where
    decEq Node' Node'                  = Just(Refl, Refl)
    decEq InsNode' InsNode'            = Just(Refl, Refl)
    decEq (String' s1) (String' s2)
                | s1 == s2             = Just (Refl, Refl)
                | otherwise            = Nothing
    decEq Empty' Empty'                = Just(Refl, Refl)
    decEq _ _                          = Nothing

    fields Node' (Node s t1 t2)        = Just (CCons s (CCons t1 (CCons t2 CNil)))
    fields InsNode' (InsNode s t1 t2)  = Just (CCons s (CCons t1 (CCons t2 CNil)))
    fields (String' _) _               = Just CNil
    fields Empty' Empty                = Just CNil
    fields _ _                         = Nothing

    apply Node' (CCons s (CCons t1 (CCons t2 CNil)))    = Node s t1 t2
    apply InsNode' (CCons s (CCons t1 (CCons t2 CNil))) = InsNode s t1 t2
    apply (String' s) CNil                              = s
    apply Empty' CNil                                   = Empty

    string Node'       = "Node"
    string InsNode'    = "InsNode"
    string (String' s) = show s
    string Empty'      = "Empty"


instance Type TreeFamily Tree where
    constructors = [ Concr Node', Concr InsNode', Concr Empty' ]

instance Type TreeFamily String where
    constructors = [ Abstr String' ]


-- Input trees --

before :: Tree
before =
  Node "root"
    (Node "A"
      (Empty)
      (Empty)
    )
    (Empty)

after :: Tree
after =
  Node "root"
    (Node "A"
      (Node "B" Empty Empty)
      (Empty)
    )
    (Empty)


{-
Function for modifying the edit script

The objective is to transform edit script fragments of the form
    ... $ Ins Node $ ...
to
    ... $ Ins InsNode $ ...
-}

processEdit :: (Family f) => EditScriptL f txs tys -> EditScriptL f txs tys
processEdit End         = End
processEdit (Ins  c  d) = Ins  c   (processEdit d)
processEdit (Del  c  d) = Del  c   (processEdit d)
processEdit (CpyTree d) = CpyTree  (processEdit d)
processEdit (Cpy  c  d) = Cpy  c   (processEdit d)


-- Test --

-- For some reason, this signature is required for type inference to work --
runDiff :: EditScript TreeFamily Tree Tree
runDiff = diff before after

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn ("before     = " ++ (show before))
  putStrLn ("after      = " ++ (show after))

  let edit = runDiff
  putStrLn ("edit       = " ++ (show edit))

  let compressed = compress edit
  putStrLn ("compressed = " ++ (show compressed))

  let processed = processEdit compressed
  putStrLn ("processed  = " ++ (show processed))

  let result = patch edit before
  putStrLn ("result     = " ++ (show result))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just specialize `processEdit` to be on `TreeFamily` (because obviously what you're trying to accomplish is specific to `TreeFamily`) and pattern match on the (first) argument to `Ins`.

```
processEdit :: EditScriptL TreeFamily txs tys -> EditScriptL TreeFamily txs tys
processEdit End         = End
processEdit (Ins  Node' d) = Ins  InsNode'   (processEdit d)
processEdit (Ins  c  d) = Ins  c (processEdit d)
processEdit (Del  c  d) = Del  c   (processEdit d)
processEdit (CpyTree d) = CpyTree  (processEdit d)
processEdit (Cpy  c  d) = Cpy  c   (processEdit d)
```

However, I do not like this approach. It requires modifying your original datatype and you lose the type-level distinction between an "original" tree and a "patched" tree. A better solution would be to create another datatype (eg. `ChangedTree`) and reimplement `patch' :: EditScriptL TreeFamily Tree Tree -> Tree -> ChangedTree`. If you keep track of both insertions and deletions, might you need a "replace"-type change as well?

Oh and, `runDiff` needs the type-signature because otherwise it doesn't know what `Type _ Tree` instance to use. eg. `diff @TreeFamily before after` (TypeApplications extension) would fix it. Haskell's typeclasses are open, so it won't automatically infer that you want `instance Type TreeFamily Tree` rather than some other `instance Type XXX Tree`, just because it can't see any other suitable `XXX` in scope right now doesn't mean that it will guess that's what you intended to use.

Comment: The suggested change to processEdit has the desired effect.

Comment: Regarding the suggestion to implement a new type for the changed tree, there are two reasons why I would prefer not to do this:

1. The Tree data type shown in my example is cut down from the real application.  The latter already has a generic node type, which has attributes including a list of labels.  I plan to use these labels to indicate the insertion / deletion.  I realise a strictly typed approach would usually be preferred in Haskell, but using labels fits better with my application.

Comment: 2. From looking at Diff.hs, the patch function depends on a large number of sub-functions.  The assumption that the input and output trees have the same type is deeply baked into the signatures of these functions.  Therefore implementing patch' would require re-implementing a large part of the underlying library code.

Comment: @GarethStockwell, that sounds like a great improvement you could contribute to the library!

Comment: @dfeuer This program is the first Haskell I have ever written. I'm trying to walk before I can run :)

Comment: This is already more running than walking lol unless you come from Idris or something like that. The internals of gdiff look pretty hairy to me, I just had an intuition about how to fix it that was roughly correct and didnt require me to understand more deeply. Original author of gdiff posted here (can't link rn) that he might write it differently if using updated GHC generics.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28707547/is-the-gdiff-library-obsolete

Comment: @ATayler can you see a way to transform `$ Del Node $` into `$ Ins DelNode $`?  I have tried to add an override to processEdit, but can't see how to make the type signatures of Del and Ins line up appropriately.  If you have any suggestions, could you please expand your answer to include them?

Comment: @ATayler re walking and running, my background is mostly C and Python - so I'm feeling more than a little lost in the world of Haskell at the moment :)  Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: @GarethStockwell I tried for a couple mins but it's not straightforward. I would roll custom diff / patch functions, that's not difficult.